# Как мне получить реальный правый margin?

Tags: css

Вопрос по CSS. Пишу разметку:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
        }

        #one {
          width: 1200px;
          height: 100px;
          margin: 10px;
          background-color: red;
        }

        #two {
          width: 1500px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: green;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</body>
```

Получаю это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда левый и правый margin не равны auto и width не равна auto, то сначала ставится левый margin, потом располагается содержимое с указанной шириной width , а правый margin сбрасывается в auto и подгоняется под ширину содержимого блока-родителя.

**Как мне получить реальный правый margin?** Написано, что он 10 пикселей, но видно, что там намного больше - оранжевым подсвечено. window.getComputedStyle() дает 10 пикселей ширины.

**Почему браузер в моем примере врет и говорит, что правый маргин 10 пикселей, хотя там все 50 пикселей?**

В данной ситуации у меня `margin-left` не `auto`, `margin-right` не `auto` и ширина не `auto` - в такой ситуации браузер должен сбросить `margin-right` в авто. Ширина поля справа будет определена в соответствии с правилом о том, что значение auto ДОПОЛНЯЕТ общую ширину элемента до ширины его блока-контейнера. источник - Эрик Мейер "css подробное руководство", страница 197

---

```
var one = document.getElementById('one');
```

`one.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().right` - эта штука работает относительно области просмотра. если прокрутить горизонтальную полосу прокрутки, то значения меняются. `one.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().right` - это "дай мне расстояние от левого края вьюпорта до правого края боди"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так это не правый маржин а (ширина блока телесного цвета - ширина фиолетового блока - левый маржин) которая в данном случае больше правого маржина. Также добавлю что код в вопросе проблему не демонстрирует никак.

Comment: на экран левый маргин просто не влез. слева тоже полоса оранжевая. сейчас исправлю картинку.блок верхний вообще красный. фиолетовым он получился потому, что я его выделил в девтулс - красный + голубой= фиолетовый. содержимое блока голубого цвета, паддинг желтого цвета, маргин оранжевый - это даже на маленькой картинке блочной чидно

Comment: У вас `margin` равен `10px`...

Comment: правый маргин не равен 10 пикселей - визуально он где-то 50 пикселей. на картинку посмотрите. 10 пикселей - это верхний, левый и правый маргины

Comment: я понял. при разности все равно, где точка отсчета

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию `div` имеет стиль `display:block`. Это значение заставляет браузер делать перенос строк в начале и в конце содержимого. **Фактически, это означает, что справа от блока не должно быть элементов.**

*Margin* в принципе — это отступ, а не какая-то определенная зона. Отступы могут объединяться с соседними отступами, выходить за пределы родительских элементов, т.е. вести себя не как *padding* или *border*.  Попробуйте так-же указать отрицательный *margin* (да, такое можно).

Исходя из этого, что выгоднее показать в девтулс: ваш 10px отступ, или то, что справа от блока не должно быть элементов?

Если вы установите `display:inline-block`, что позволяет блокам оказываться на одной строке, и тогда в девтулс вы увидите ваш 10px отступ.

```css
div {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отрицательный маржин можно указать, но это как если бы банки использовали отрицательные проценты - старый 2002-й год, без шуток говоря, с нынешней поддержкой браузеров - себе морока.

Comment: @VostokSisters отрицательный margin определен в спецификации: [«Negative values for margin properties are allowed»](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#margin-properties)

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем случае можно так:

```js
~function () {
  var one = document.getElementById('one');
  var res = one.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().right - one.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  console.log(res)
}()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

```js
function getMR() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one');
  var res = one.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().right - one.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  console.log(res);
}

document.getElementById('log').addEventListener('click', getMR);
getMR();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  width: 4000px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#log {
  position: fixed;
  right: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  padding: .25em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<button id="log">Log</button>
```

Comment: что это за запись ~function () {...}()? не видел никогда такого

Comment: @Dimon, обычная самовызывающаяся функция, чтоб скоуп ограничить :)

Comment: ~ - этот знак смутил

Comment: @Dimon, бывает, часто)))

Comment: one.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().right - эта штука работает относительно области просмотра. если прокрутить горизонтальную полосу прокрутки, то значения меняются. one.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().right - это "дай мне расстояние от левого края вьюпорта до правого края боди"

Comment: Qwertiy, вы не в курсе, почему браузер  в моем примере врет и говорит, что правый маргин 10 пикселей, хотя там все 50 пикселей?

Comment: @Dimon, не правда. Скролл не влияет на результат. Добавил кнопку в сниппет. Последний вопрос не понял. Вероятно, т. к. в css прописано 10.

Comment: не знаю, правда это или нет, но у меня так получилось. добавил картинку в вопрос (внизу вопроса), на картинке это видно. до прокрутки выдает 1006 пикселей, после - 514

Comment: @Dimon, но я вывожу разность, а не это значение. Да, они зависят от видимой области, но они оба одинаково зависят он неё и разность не меняется. Чем не устраивает?

Comment: я понял. при разности все равно, где точка отсчета

Comment: - "почему браузер в моем примере врет и говорит, что правый маргин 10 пикселей, хотя там все 50 пикселей?" - "Последний вопрос не понял. Вероятно, т. к. в css прописано 10".  я имею в виду то, что в данной ситуации у меня левый маргин не auto, правый маргин не auto и ширина  не auto - в такой ситуации браузер должен сбросить маргин правый в авто. ширина поля справа будет определена в соответствии с правилом о том, что значение auto ДОПОЛНЯЕТ общую ширину элемента до ширины его блока-контейнера. источник - эрик мейер css подробное руководство

Comment: @Dimon, не знаю. Отрисовано же правильно. Тут надо js'ную спецификацию смотреть про getComputedStyle. Вроде логично, что он взял десятку из css.